# How to pass in extra arguments when starting a child worker of a Supervisor in OTP?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
defmodule NestedSupervisorTree do
  # this will be the top line supervisor
  use Supervisor

  def start_link, do: Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      supervisor(BranchSupervisor, [], restart: :temporary)
      #worker(TreeWorker, [], restart: :temporary)
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)

  end

  def start_branch(args) do
    {_, branch_id} = Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [args])
  end
end

defmodule BranchSupervisor do
  # this will be the top line supervisor
  use Supervisor

  def start_link(args), do: Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [args], name: __MODULE__)

  def init(args) do
    IO.puts "branch init args:"
    IO.inspect args
    children = [
      worker(TreeWorker, [args], restart: :temporary)
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
  end

  def start_worker do
    {_, wid} = Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [3])
  end
end

defmodule TreeWorker do
  def start_link(args) do
    IO.puts "worker args:"
    IO.inspect args
    #IO.puts String.codepoints raw
    {:ok, spawn(fn -> loop end)}
  end

  def loop do
    receive do
      :stop -> :ok

      msg ->
        IO.inspect msg
        loop
    end
  end
end
```

Suppose I issue the following commands in the iex terminal in the following order:

```
 iex> {_, pid} = NestedSupervisorTree.start_link
 iex> {_, cid} = NestedSupervisorTree.start_branch(2)
 iex> BranchSupervisor.start_worker
 # returns:
{:error,
 {:EXIT,
  {:undef,
   [{TreeWorker, :start_link, [[2], 3], []},
    {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 359]},
    {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 384]},
    {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 629]},
    {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 661]},
    {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 240]}]}}}
```

How do I inject "extra arguments" in the call to BranchSupervisor.start_worker?  If I remove the "3" in `{_, wid} = Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [3])` everyting works. Is this even the right thing to do?

This is mostly a learning exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[3]` here is being appended to the `args` passed to `worker` in `BranchSupervisor.init/1`, which is `[[2]]`, making the final arguments `[[2]] ++ [3]` => `[[2], 3]`. Since the list is two element long, the Supervisor is then calling `TreeWorker.start_link/2` like `TreeWorker.start_link([2], 3)`, so if you want to accept two arguments like this, you just need to change `start_link` to accept two arguments:

```
defmodule TreeWorker do
  def start_link(arg1, arg2) do
    # `arg1 == [2]` and `arg2 == 3` here
    ...
  end
end
```

This behavior is documented in [`Supervisor.start_child/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_child/2):

> In the case of `:simple_one_for_one`, the child specification defined in
>   the supervisor is used and instead of a `child_spec`, an arbitrary list
>   of terms is expected. The child process will then be started by
>   appending the given list to the existing function arguments in the
>   child specification.

Comment: Thanks, is this type of stuff usually called out in the docs somewhere? I looked in Supervisor.start_child, and perhaps I missed it since it's late...

Comment: Yes, it's documented in `Supervisor.start_child/2`. I've added a link and relevant quote to the answer.